# AES GCM - ciphertext is different everytime

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, aes-gcm

I have the following code in python:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

key = b'\x19\x3c\x04\x27\xf6\xa2\x1a\x08\x7f\xb0\x1c\xe9\xa7\x92\x3d\xd8\xe5\xc7\xae\x98\xf5\x0b\xf4\xa3\x7b\x4f\xd6\x76\x95\xd3\xe0\xd9'
data = b'\x47\x56\x64\xc1\x54\xe7\xa1\xed\x92\x4b\x26\x06\x6f\x4e\x95\x30\xea\xc4\x08\xf7\xdc\x69\x1c\x38\x38\xff\x38\x58\x50\x78\x9f\xd9\x32\xea\x86\xcd\x8c\x6d\x8f\x17\x30\x2a\xae\x6e\xa1\xc6\x6d'

header = b'\xdb\xd2\xed\x76\x3c\x50\xf2\x7c\xe3\xbe\x78\xa9\xc3\x6b'

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM)
cipher.update(header)
cipherText, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

print(cipherText)
```

The ciphertext seemed to be changing everytime.

Any idea why that is?

Comment: GCM requires a nonce, and if you don't provide one PyCryptodome creates a random nonce (you can get it with `cipher.nonce`). The ciphertext should be different each time, that's normal. You can decrypt it correctly if you have the nonce.

Comment: So even if key, data, and header are static, ciphertext still changes?

Comment: Yes it does, if you use a different nonce. GCM uses CTR for encryption, and so it is important to use a different nonce for each encryption.

Comment: It's important to make clear here: if you encrypt multiple messages with the same key and same nonce, it completely breaks the security of GCM (as it does with most other counter-based modes). It doesn't just reduce security somewhat (like reusing IVs in CBC). It completely undermines the entire encryption scheme. You must never reuse a nonce for a given key. If the ciphertext isn't different every time in GCM, the encryption is worthless. (With modes like CBC, it's just relatively insecure; but with GCM, it's completely broken.)